# Set graphic card to extremly low resolution

Tags: linux, graphics

I want to make big **LED matrix display** with low resolution. This display will have probably resolution of **32x32** and will be connected directly to **DVI** output of graphic card.
The only trouble I have is to set graphic card to such low resolution. Does anybody know way of doing this? Preferably on linux, preferably as second screen.
**Is it possible with custom made driver? Or some special graphic card?** Because usualy graphic card allows user to choose only from small set of resolutions.
Or is this comletely impossible?

Comment: With such a low resolution why don't you just drive every LED completely by software?

Comment: I don't want just to print some text or picture on the display. I want to play videos on it. There is number of disadvantages with software solution. 1. I would need extra HW(my own low resolution graphic card). Which would be time consuming. 2. I would need to write my own driver for my "graphic card". I don't have skill to write such driver. And if I'm right writing driver for eighter linux or windows is not easy task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 5 months I didn't find better solution than this:
I don't know a way of setting 32x32 resolution, so I will set lowest possible (e.g. 640x480). My LED matrix screen will then "listen" only to first 32 pixels of first 32 lines and it will ignore rest of pixels. The software in PC will have to take care to display video only in upper left corner of screen.
This solution is simple and have only one disadvantage. My LED matrix display driver (I mean HW driver for LEDs) will have to deal with higher frequency of data on DVI. But I think on 640x480 frequencies are not that high for it to be very difficult.